# Why BindValue does NOT yield results when WHERE clause is used?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement, bindvalue

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. If i omit thew WHERE clause in this query, the server returns all rows from the database. SO I know that part works.  If I use the WHERE CLAUSE i.e.

WHERE name='$name' AND loc='$loc' -

I get results but when I use the bindValue or if I pass the binder in the execute command I get no error and no data

```
    $stmt = "SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ID=table2.fkID".
            " WHERE name = :name AND loc = :loc";

    $binder = array(':name' => $name, ':loc' => $loc);
```

This if the function that takes those parameters

```
public function fetchData($stmt, $binder = array())
    {
        $DB = new PDO(........);
        $STMT =  $DB->prepare($stmt);

        foreach ($binder as $key => $value):
            $k = (is_numeric($key)) ? $key + 1 : $key;
            if (is_int($value)):
                $STMT->bindValue($k, (int) $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            else:
                $STMT->bindValue($k, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            endif;
        endforeach;

        try {
            $STMT->execute();
            return $STMT->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($this->error = $e->getMessage());
        }
```

What am I doing wrong here. Sorry guys i searched all questions similar but I have no answer.

Comment: Should `:loc` be quoted, like `:name` is?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. That was just a typo, it is quoted in the actual code. I fixed it above. Still No results Thanks Andrewsi for such a fast response

Comment: That would suggest that the query is failing somewhere, then - have you tried adding debugging statements in your function so you can make sure it's doing what you expect it to be doing, and whether the database is return an error code?

Comment: Oh not yet, I guess I will try that... Thanks again! If you come across another suggestion please let me know...

Comment: Still No luck! Anyone... I need help guys! Could this have something to do with the settings on the server?

Comment: What did your debugging show?

Comment: Oh I found out where the problem was! In the code above after this line: $k = (is_numeric($key)) ? $key + 1 : $key; - I didn't call $value like this: $v = $value; Then I needed to add the $v in my foreach statement instead of the $value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by re-writing my code again:

```
foreach ($binder as $key => $value):
            $k = (is_numeric($key)) ? $key + 1 : $key;
            $v = $value;
            if (is_int($v)):
                $STMT->bindValue($k, (int) $v, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            else:
                $STMT->bindValue($k, $v, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            endif;
        endforeach;
```

Note the $v used in the foreach statement instead of the original $value;